# Rally 2.0SDK using Login API and Javascript

Tags: rally

I am looking to create an external webpage for Rally so some of our non-rally users can view some custom screens.

I have researched quite a bit and see that the 1.xx can use LoginKey and I did get that working.  However, I also read some messages about the ApiKey for 2.0 seems to be rolling out.  I checked the gitHub but didnt see any examples out there.

I am looking for something pretty easy ( I think ), just something that cycles through all the releases with a certain critera (ReleaseStartDate > today).

I want to customize their output a bit, so not just put into a grid.  Are there any examples yet of using the new API?  Or should I use the 1.xx

Answer (score 0):

API Keys are fully supported by SDK 2.0.  Here is a guide to get started: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps

Comment: Kyle,  Thanks for the help.  I cant seem to get it to work.  I can get the loginkey to work for a rally api 1.25 to work.  But when I try to get a 2.0rc1 app, it just doesnt work.  To be clear, I put the app up on the web, hit the URL, then append the ?apiKey=_1212xxx.  When I do all this, it still brings up the login box.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Api Keys work for 2.0rc3 and above.  You'll need to upgrade your app to a newer version if you're still using rc1...